# TypeError: this._nativeModule.addListener is not a function

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am getting following error while running react native app in IOS (Xcode v14.3.1React Native 0.63.2Architecture: Apple Silicon M1 Max):

`TypeError: this._nativeModule.addListener is not a function. (In 'this._nativeModule.addListener(eventType)', 'this._nativeModule.addListener' is undefined)`

`ERROR Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)`

Can someone help on how to resolve this error?

[ERROR log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQ6Be.png)

Tried uninstalling `node_modules` and `pods`, but the error persists.

Comment: No updates yet, issue seems to be with some library